# I'm getting an error on my landing page after the user logs in

Tags: reactjs

Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined is the error

I'm a bit of new comer when it comes to react and i've just made a user login system for my college project but i'm getting this error after I login in and try access the landing page, this is the code i have the landing page. Any advice would be really appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import $ from 'jquery';
import { Login } from './Login.Component';
import MovieRow from '../MovieRow';


export class Landingpage extends React.Component {


render = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <table className="titleBar">
        <tbody> 
            <tr>
              <td>
                <h1>IADT Project</h1>
              </td>  
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

<input style ={{
  fontSize: 24,
  display: 'block',
  width: "99%",
  paddingTop: 8,
  paddingBottom: 8,
  paddingLeft: 16,
}}onChange={this.searchChangeHandler.bind(this)}  placeholder="Enter search term" />
</div>
  )
}
}
export default Landingpage;
```

Comment: where is the searchChangeHandler ?

Comment: Seems like you haven't defined the method searchChangeHandler() in the component LandingPage

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-j2e1w2 Since .bind() creates a new function each time it is run, this method would lead to a new function being created every time the render function executes. remove bind keep it simple like {this.searchChangeHandler, and in render remove  render = () => { , keep it like  render() {}

Answer (score 0):

The error state exactly the problem. You are trying to assing an OnChange method, but searchChangeHandler hasn't been declare. 
Also, the binding should be done in the constructor.

1) add a constructor in your class

2) Adds that property and assign a method binding *this* context

3) define your method

4) fix your render function

```
    export class Landingpage extends React.Component { 


      //1
      costructor (props) {
        super(props);
        //2
        this.searchChangeHandler =  this.searchChangeHandler.bind(this)
      }

      searchChangeHandler () {
        //Do something here
      }

      render = () => {
        return ({ 
          //markup code I didn't write followed by the fix
          ...
          //4
          <input  onChange={this.searchChangeHandler} />
        }) 
      }
}
```